# MySQL DB Select date removes an hour randomly from the value?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm querying a view. And when I select a date value it removes 1 hr from the value?
date_sub(date, INTERVAL -1 hr) doesn't work as a workaround. this seems to be happening randomly?

Example of values:

```
select ticket_id,
                priority,
                status,
                New_status,
                Prev_status,
                message_date, 
                status_time_duration,
                lead(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lead_new_status,
                lag(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_status,
                lead(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id, message_date desc) lead_new_message_date,
                lag(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_message_date
            from v_ticket_status_history
```

Results:

[image]

When I put it in a subselect, it changes the datetime for some reason!

```
select ticket_id,
    priority, 
    status, 
    case when new_status='Open' and prev_status= 'New' then message_date else 0 end as open_ticket_date /*2021-12-17 12:16:39 2021-10-18 06:11:50 */
    from ( 
            select ticket_id,
                priority,
                status,
                New_status,
                Prev_status,
                message_date, 
                status_time_duration,
                lead(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lead_new_status,
                lag(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_status,
                lead(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id, message_date desc) lead_new_message_date,
                lag(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_message_date
            from v_ticket_status_history
            )a;
```

Result:

[image]

I really don't understand why this happens. From one value it removes 1 hour, from the second value it removes 2 hrs!
Any advice?

Kind regards,
Rosa

Answer (score 0):

Add A GROUP BY and a MAX for the date

```
select ticket_id,
    priority, 
    status, 
   MAX( case when new_status='Open' and prev_status= 'New' then message_date else 0 end) as open_ticket_date /*2021-12-17 12:16:39 2021-10-18 06:11:50 */
    from ( 
            select ticket_id,
                priority,
                status,
                New_status,
                Prev_status,
                message_date, 
                status_time_duration,
                lead(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lead_new_status,
                lag(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_status,
                lead(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id, message_date desc) lead_new_message_date,
                lag(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_message_date
            from v_ticket_status_history
            )a
    GROUP BY ticket_id,
    priority, 
    status;
```

This will show the higest date for all ticket, priority and status

Comment: Hi @nbk , the results are the same. I think this is a bug or something. Can it be it's because I'm querying a view and not a table?

Comment: that shouldn't be the same result, please add a [mre] so that i can check it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up filtering the subselect and selecting the max(message_date) value. This returned correct values.

```
select ticket_id,
    priority, 
    status, 
    max(message_date) open_ticket_date-- ,
    -- max(case when new_status='Open' and prev_status= 'New' then message_date else 0 end) as  open_ticket_date /*2021-12-17 12:16:39 2021-10-18 06:11:50 */
    from ( 
            select ticket_id,
                priority,
                status,
                New_status,
                Prev_status,
                message_date,
                status_time_duration,
                lead(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lead_new_status,
                lag(New_status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status  order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_status,
                lead(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id, message_date desc) lead_new_message_date,
                lag(message_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, priority, status   order by ticket_id,message_date desc) lag_new_message_date
            from v_ticket_status_history
            wherenew_status='Open'and prev_status= 'New'
            )a  
        group by ticket_id,
    priority, 
    status
```

Result: [image]

Thank you all!
Rosa